# android + scala + obfuscate code

Tags: android, scala, obfuscation

I am trying to build "final APK" with obfuscated Scala code.
I have Eclipse + plugins: ADT, Scala, AndroidProguardScala.

When I select:
*myproject <- right click to show ctx menu > Android Tools > Export Unsigned Application Package*
there is generated APK but Scala code is not obfuscated.

On the other hand: enabling proguard in APT build config with:
*proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt*
generates hundreds of warnings and finally fails.

**Wondering how to convince IDE to generate APK with obfuscated Scala code.**

BTW. Maybe there is no purely IDE based solution? I saw sbt plugins for Android. Maybe these need to be used?

- https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin
- https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd *highly* recommend leaving the IDE and diving into the sbt world for developing Scala apps (esp. with Scala/Android). I've been developing a pet project some time ago, it uses proguard and the config is embedded in the Build.scala there, you can have a look at: https://github.com/ktoso/kanbanery-tv/blob/master/project/Build.scala

Other than that you'll want to read up about the latest version of: https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin (or join the mailing lists mentioned there where all the scala+android people hang out.)